# How to change status of wordpress post after period of time?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a wordpress site where users can upload products. The default product status is pending,however I want to change it to published if it has passed 12 hours after the post_time.

I am using woocommerce.
I´ve tried to use *wp_insert_post_data*:

```
function reset_post_date_wpse_121565($data,$postarr) {
    if ($data['post_type'] == 'product'){
        $data['post_date'] = '2018-06-03 22:50:00';
    } 
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','reset_post_date_wpse_121565');
```

But it sets the post to published, what can I do to accomplish this auto update?

Comment: So you wish to publish the products after 12 hours automatically am i get you correctly ?

Comment: You need also to set the `post_status` to `future`

Answer (score 0):

You can try WordPress Cron run to achieve this,

```
function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {


 $schedules['every_tewlve_hours'] = array(
        'interval' => 43200, // Every 12 hours
        'display'  => __( 'Every 12 hours' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );

//Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_cron_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_tewlve_hours', 'myprefix_cron_hook' );
}

///Hook into that action that'll fire every six hours
 add_action( 'myprefix_cron_hook', 'myprefix_cron_function' );

//create your function, that runs on cron
function myprefix_cron_function() {
    $args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'post_status'   => array( 'pending' ),
    'author'        => $userid
   );
   $pending_posts = get_posts( $args ); 
//update status code
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more example visit,

[wp cron demo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103938/how-to-display-pending-posts-on-the-homepage-only-for-editors)